# Stop macOS from ejecting external disks on logout

Tags: time-machine, mojave, external-disk, sharing, server.app

I have a Mac Mini running 10.14.6 and hosting file sharing and Time Machine backups on an external drive.  Every time a user logs out of the console, the external drive is ejected.  This happens even if the drive is being actively used by a remote user.

A different Mac Mini, also running 10.14.6, does not have this problem. That system has had multiple generations of upgrades, and was running Server.app at one point, so there are many configuration differences which could account for the difference in behavior.

Is there a particular configuration, preference, or other setting that will stop macOS from unmounting external disks every time a user logs out of the console?